# How much rework do i have to do when moving from simple automation to Page Object Model framework using Cucumber and Selenium/Capybara?

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara, rubymine

My Goal is to create a Page Object Model Automation framework using Cucumber with capybara/selenium for mu client project. Currently my knowledge related to Page Object Model gem is very limited and at the same time i want to show some delivery by creating automation scripts using cucumber and capybara. So i am in the process of creating some feature files and subsequent step definitions.

So my question is, If i move to simple automation to POM framework, how much rework i have to do in terms of scripts and also if this approach is correct. Please guide me as i am pretty new to ruby automation.

Answer (score 0):

Well this can be a very opinionated question, but I'll try to keep it simple:

If you already have well structured and modularised code (cucumber features and step defs), it won't take significant changes to move to POM. Its essentially a different structuring technique to keep your code organised and keep your changes minimal/confined.

Gems like [siteprism](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism) can help you with creating well structured page objects, if you are open to learn an additional DSL (for siteprism) on top of cucumber / capybara. Or you can roll out your own without any additional libraries, though it would demand a thorough understanding of POM architecture and best practices.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have a little work to migrate and meet increasingly the tool, the Framework POM only shows speed gain when you have some pages that already are mapped, it might take some time to be shown in reports, but I believe it has much to gain, organization, clarity and speed are some of the advantages of migration.

In my work I help other QAs learning and use POM in one day, a lot of guys use xpath to find objects, I just show how they can reuse that xpaths in a page object.

The second step I show to use method, not only elements, then they can reuse a lot of code and stop repeat steps, find where they break and use a simple method in siteprism page, example:

```
element :field_login , :xpath, "login"
element :field_password, :xpath, "password"
element :login_button, :xpath, "login_button"

def authenticate (username, password)
    field_login.set username
    field.password.set password

    LoginPage.new if login_button.click
end
```

My next step is show to leave to use xpath and use css elements.

And after some sprints, they understand the beneficts of the framework, and it is default for all automation, include the DEVs can understand and help in tests now.

Answer (score 0):

Warning this answer is somewhat controversial.

I'd say don't bother using the Page Object Model, its fundamentally flawed. The web is about resources and representations (REST) not about pages. BDD is about behaviour, not pages.

The danger with POM (particularly when you are not experienced) is that you write lots of scenarios to test what is on each page. When really what you should be doing is writing scenarios that confirm that some behaviour exists.